# Size of indexed vectors in Chroma db

Tags: chromadb, vector-database

I read the documentation of Chroma DB, vector database,  but couldn't find out what is the maximum size for indexed vectors? Can anyone tell me where to find that information?

Answer (score 0):

Can refer this link provided in chroma db documentation which has all sentence Transformer models for embedding supported by chroma db:

https://docs.trychroma.com/embeddings

It also supports embeddings from openai, cohere, PaLM, etc.
Based on these list of models gives, max dimension can be 1536.